# git branching strategy for a new project with a small dev team

Tags: git, git-branch

We are a team of 3 members and we are about create a new iOS project in git.
As a small team, all three developers will work on all modules.

Is it better to create a separate branch for each developer and merge to master when we deploy onto production server?

Is it okay to work all developers on the same master branch?

Can any one please suggest me best git branching strategy for new new project?

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't want to wade into the religious waters of determining a best branching strategy, I think it's safe to say that developers should not commit to master willy-nilly.

A typical strategy is to have a developer create a separate branch for each feature or bugfix so that decisions on whether and when to merge into master can be made on a feature-by-feature (branch-by-branch) basis. If you are unsure what your workflow should be, I would recommend going with something along those lines unless you have a very good reason to deviate.

A commonly-cited explication of this sort of approach is at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.

Comment: Thank you, creating a separate branch for each feature would be good for updating the existing project but we are at the beginning of creating a new project. There would be a situation where two developers would modify the same file. If we maintain separate branches, will it satisfy my need?

Comment: @satyanarayana: Concurrent work on the same files is doable regardless of whether you're working on separate branches. It can be quite painful either way. It's important to understand that with Git you're never _really_ working on the same branch. Each team member's work takes place in their local branches, to which they can commit independently of the other team members. Whether this local branch is published to the rest of the team as a separate branch or if it's merged directly to the shared branch is a pure process question.

Comment: @Trott: You've already waded into the religious waters by saying that everyone committing to master is an anti-pattern. What I _think_ you're saying is that everyone pushing straight into the branch without prior review is a bad idea. I'd agree with that, but avoiding it doesn't imply that you need to create (published) branches for every logical change. For example, a code review tool like Gerrit allow people to base their work on e.g. master (discouraging diverging branches) yet still have the ability to gate what actually goes into the branch.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thanks for the thoughtful comment. I've edited my answer to hopefully be more clear or at least less dogmatic